# Conditionally open url in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I have a page that currently redirects if a check box is selected and then a "submit" button clicked:

```
if  request.Form("myCheckbox") = "on" then
        response.Redirect("/newPage.asp?txt="staff"")
else
        response.Redirect("/thisPage.asp")
end if
```

If the check box is selected, I'd like it to open in a new tab.
I gather from similar questions on here that this can't be done in HTML and would probably be best achieved with Javascript but am unclear as to how to proceed beyond the following:

```
function sendForm(action){
     if (document.getElementById('myCheckbox').checked) {
         window.open('/newPage.asp?txt="staff"', '_blank')
     }
}
```

I know it's wrong as it stays on the same page but that's as far I've managed.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've found out, a new tab/window cannot be opened from the server using Classic ASP.

Your 'window.open' line is correct and should fire so I assume the problem is with the function and/or the ID of your checkbox.

See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DAC84/fghgy69a/1/) for a working example, or below for the code.

```
document.getElementById('yourForm').addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    if (document.getElementById('myCheckbox').checked) {
        window.open('http://www.jsfiddle.net', '_blank');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```